# Where should general purpose Laravel functions be outside a controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

Normally in a Laravel app I put functions in controllers.

But if I have general purpose functions like AWS API calls I need to access from multiple controllers, how do I do it? I have a provider, but can't access it?

Previously I have used something like:

```
$servers = new ServerController();
$stats = $servers->groupStats();
```

But this doesn't work with the service provider/constructor, which someone else has added to the project:

app/Providers/AutoScalingClientProvider.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Aws\AutoScaling\AutoScalingClient;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AutoScalingClientProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(AutoScalingClient::class, function () {
            return new AutoScalingClient([
                'AutoScalingGroupName' => config('aws.auto_scaling_client.name'),
                'region' => config('aws.auto_scaling_client.region'),
                'version' => config('aws.auto_scaling_client.version')
            ]);
        });
    }

}
```

app/Helpers/AwsAutoscale.php:

```
<?php namespace App\Helpers;

use Aws\AutoScaling\AutoScalingClient;

class AwsAutoscale {

    private $awsClient;

    public function __construct(AutoScalingClient $awsClient)
    {
        $this->awsClient = $awsClient;
    }

    /**
     * Returns an excerpt from a given string (between 0 and passed limit variable).
     *
     * @param $string
     * @param int $limit
     * @param string $suffix
     * @return string
     */
    public static function helloworld()
    {
        return 'helloworld';
    }


    /**
     * Gets the stats for our auto scaling worker group.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection The group stats.
     */
    public function groupStats()
    {
        $result = $this->awsClient->describeAutoScalingGroups();

        return collect([
            'desired' => $result['AutoScalingGroups'][0]['DesiredCapacity'],
            'min' => $result['AutoScalingGroups'][0]['MinSize'],
            'max' => $result['AutoScalingGroups'][0]['MaxSize'],
            'current' => count($result['AutoScalingGroups'][0]['Instances'])
        ]);
    }


}
```

I can call helloworld() from anywhere and that works, but calling groupstats() gives error:

> Non-static method App\Helpers\AwsAutoscale::groupStats() should not be called statically

I realise this structure is wrong. How should I set this sort of thing up? I just want to be able to call something like AwsAutoscale::groupstats() from any controller.

Comment: @SougataBose Yes, but I will have lots of these, not just one function. I don't want a helpers.php file with 50+ functions with many `use` statements, I want things where they should be. Plus, I'm not the only person on this project.

Answer (score 0):

The function groupstats() is not defined as static therefor it can not be called via `AwsAutoscale::groupstats()`.

You either need to change the function definition of the `groupstats()` to `public static function groupStats()` or call the function via `$AwsAutoscale->groupstats()` where `$AwsAutoscale` needs to be a instance of the class!

Comment: Adding static doesn't work. Then it won't access `$this`?

Comment: You could implement a facade https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/facades wrapping the creation of the service behind a "static" facade!

Answer (score -1):

As I see, you try to call a `non-static function` statically (`AwsAutoscale::groupStats()`).
The function `helloworld` was declared as static, so no problem to call it in this way, then you have 3 solutions: First to define `groupStats` as a static function then it works, the second solution to instantiate your class `$awsAutoscale = \App::make(AwsAutoscale::class)` and then $awsAutoscale->groupStats(), or last solution to make AwsAutoscale as a helper class, then you can just make groupstats().

Comment: If it's static then `$this->awsAutoscale` doesn't work? How do I access what is in the AutoScalingClientProvider?

Comment: Where would I put `$awsAutoscale = \App::make(AwsAutoscale::class)`? I can't make that work? I just get `Call to undefined method App\Helpers\AwsAutoscale::describeAutoScalingGroups()`

Comment: where you want to use the function? in the provider? then there you can make the instantiation